# Sencha Touch Panel Render Issue on Load

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Long story short: I've got a mainPanel which consists of a tabBar on the bottom and a docked toolBar on top.

From a tabPanel that is selected, I have elements inside of it, in this case other buttons. On a button tap, I want to load a different panel that I've created, which is not one of the tabBar panels.

So I'm hiding the current tabPanel and showing the panel that is tied to the button click. I can get it to show up. The issue is that the panel that shows doesn't render correctly until I actually rotate the device. The image / items on the panel are usually off to the bottom right.

Sometimes the toolbar that I have attached to the new panel disappears completely as well. I'm clueless as to why this is happening, and hoping someone can explain to me what I need to do. I'm using the latest version of Sencha Touch 1.x.

fyi: this is a xpost from (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171567-Loading-another-panel-causes-incorrect-rendering...&p=710474#post710474). I wasn't getting an answer that made sense so I'm coming to SO for hopefully some assistance.

### Code Snippets Below:

### INITIAL TAB FROM TABPANEL

```
var TAB1 = {
title: "TAB1",
layout: 'vbox',

            items:[
            {html: "<h1>TAB1</h1>"},
            panel2_btn, panel3_btn, panel4_btn,
            {flex: 1},
            {html: "<h3>EMAIL US</h3>"},
            sevenday_btn
    ],
iconCls: 'TAB1',
style: "color: #2e2e2e; font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: bold",
}
```

---

### BUTTON FOR NEW PANEL

```
var panel2_btn = new Ext.Button({
centered: true,
cls: 'button',
text: 'TAP FOR PANEL2',
handler: function(e){
    mainTabPanel.hide();
    viewStack.push(panel2);
    panel2.show();

}
});
```

---

### PANEL THAT BUTTON TAP SHOULD LOAD

```
var panel2 = new Ext.Panel({
id: 'panel2',
layout: 'vbox',
fullscreen: true,
dockedItems: [
   backToolbar],
items: [
            {flex: 1},
            {html: "<h1>PANEL 2</h1><img src='resources/assets/panel2.png' id='panel2'/>"},
            {flex: 1}
]
});
```

---

### TAB PANEL

```
var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
id: 'tabPanel',
dock: 'bottom',
styleHtmlContent: true,
tabBar: {
    cls: 'tabBar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    layout: {
        pack: 'center'
    }
},
defaults: {
    scroll: 'vertical',
    layout: 'hbox'
},
items: [TAB1, TAB2, TAB3, TAB4, TAB5]
```

});

---

### MAIN PANEL CREATION

```
var mainPanel;

Ext.setup({
tabletStartupScreen: 'startup-splash-logo.png',
phoneStartupScreen: 'phone-startup-splash-logo.png',
icon: 'icon.png',
glossOnIcon: true,
fullscreen: true,
onReady: function(){
    mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'mainPanel',
        fullscreen: true,
        dockedItems: [
            toolbar
            ],
        items: [tabPanel],
        layout: 'card',
        scroll: 'vertical'
    });
}
});
```

---

### TOOLBAR CREATION

```
var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
id: 'mainToolbar',
dock: 'top',
cls: 'toolbar',
layout: {
    pack: 'justify',
    align: 'center'
},
items: [
    {xtype: 'spacer'},
    logo,
    {xtype: 'spacer'}
    ]
});
```

---

### LOGO

```
var energy_fitness_image = new Ext.BoxComponent({
centered: true,
cls: 'energy_fitness_logo'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I've noticed in your code, although your code snippets fall short to fully understand how your views are structured:

- First of all, try adding the element before hiding the active one

  ```
  viewStack.push(panel2);
  mainTabPanel.hide();
  panel2.show();
  ```
- You could call panel2 or the viewport's `doLayout()` method after adding it
- If you don't strictly need tabs, try using a viewport with a card layout. You can switch between them with `setActiveItem()` and you can add new ones to the viewport with the panel's `add()` method instead of using an array like you're doing right now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I've tried the proposed changes. The pages still aren't rendering correctly unless I rotate the device. I've just updated the above snippets to update how I'm making the mainPanel, etc.